# Open certain page on push notification using firebase cloud messaging on flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I've manage to push a notification to my flutter app using firebase cloud messaging. what I'm trying to do right now is that, once i click the notification, it will directly to a certain page that the app have. How do i redirect the notification to a certain page? thank you

Comment: Use a GlobalKey to get a reference to a widget that has a Navigator in it's context and then use this reference to navigate to a specific route.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer do you have any example or reference on how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have something like this, in my FCM class:

```
static StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>> _onMessageStreamController =
      StreamController.broadcast();
static StreamController<Map<String, dynamic>> _streamController =
      StreamController.broadcast();
static final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
static final Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> onFcmMessage =
      _streamController.stream;

static setupFCMListeners() {
    print("Registered FCM Listeners");
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _onMessageStreamController.add(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _streamController.add(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        _streamController.add(message);
      },
    );
  }

  static Widget handlePath(Map<String, dynamic> dataMap) {
    var path = dataMap["route"];
    var id = dataMap["id"];
    return handlePathByRoute(path, id);
  }

  static Widget handlePathByRoute(String route, String routeId) {
    switch (route) {
      case "user":
        return Profile(guid: routeId);
      case "event":
        return EventInfo(eventId: routeId);
      case "messaging":
        return MessagingView(guid: routeId);
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
```

My `main.dart` subscribes to onFcmMessage stream, but you don't need streams to do all this. Also, you need some code to handle stream failure and closure.

But when the app comes to foreground it gets the message on either `onMessage` callback or the `onLaunch` or `onResume` callback. Check their differences on the FCM flutter pub docs.

The methods `handlePath` and `handlePathByRoute` are methods that usually my main.dart or other classes listening to notifications call to get the path to route to, but you can simply call them directly by replacing the stream code here like:

```
static setupFCMListeners() {
    print("Registered FCM Listeners");
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("Message: $message"); // Not handling path since on notification in app it can be weird to open a new page randomly.
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        handlePath(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        handlePath(message);
      },
    );
  }
```

This honestly may not even be the best or even a good approach but due to lack of documentation, this is what I'm working with for now. I'd love to try Günter Zöchbauer's approach and save some object creation if possible!

Hope this is helpful! :)

EDIT: `Profile`, `EventInfo` and `MessagingView` are three classes that extend `StatefulWidget`, sorry if that wasn't clear.

You can also try using named routes, they make it easier like api routes and avoid a lot of imports and have a central router, but AFAIK they lacked transition configurations.

Comment: which one should be on the main.dart? And should i make a new file for the FCM class?

Comment: There's no rules for this. Just handle the callbacks onMessage, onLaunch and onResume wherever you like. I just gave you an example of what I do to handle data notification payloads. Also make sure you pass in the FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK argument from your backend. Creating a FCM class maybe helpful if you want to access FCM messages from multiple classes not just main.dart. That's been the case for me and hence I use streams to subscribe on need.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add click_action inside your notification data.

```
'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
```

see this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65597471/11230524