# how to redirect users to a page on notification click

Tags: function, flutter, cloud

I am working on flutter app and web with firebase server. I send notifications using cloud functions. I want to redirect users to a specific page when they get a notification and click on it.  For now, my app shows 'home page' when I get a notification and click on it. How can I redirect to 'request detail page' instead of 'home page' when users get a notification and click on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this inside AndroidManifest file

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Inside notification data, Add click_action and your required parameter for navigating to a specific page

```
'data': {
     'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
     'product_id': 1,
     ...
   },
```

When user click on the notification one of these three event will trigger depending on your app state.

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
  onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
    _showItemDialog(message);
  },
  onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
  onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    _navigateToItemDetail(message);
  },
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
    _navigateToItemDetail(message);
  },
);
```

Retrive the notification data from message & navigate to your desired page.

Comment: Thanks for reply Shanto, What is product_id :1? Is that just an example, or do I need to do exactly like you did?

Comment: this is just an example.

Comment: Would you please show me some example of_navigateToItemDetail(message) function?

Answer (score 0):

SecondScreen is the class name of other screen.

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

         Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SecondScreen(
                message,
              );
            }));

        print("onMessage: $message");
        _showItemDialog(message);
      },
     
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Muhammad, What about onResume and onLaunch? Do I need to write the same Navigator functions for them, too?

Comment: yes you need to write same navigator function.

Comment: I tried this, but the app still doesn't show 'request detail page'. It only shows 'home page'

Comment: yes you have to navigate on each type of message like onMessage, onBackgroundMessage, onResume. if this is not happening then print something inside these messages may be these functions are not called when you click on notification. Like the below code
onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onMessage: $message");
  },